# Custom fonts with tailwindcss-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, tailwind-css

In a Rails 7 app with the `tailwindcss-rails` gem I'm trying to add some custom fonts.

1. I have created the `app/assets/fonts` folder and added the `.woff` files.
2. I have updated `config/tailwind.config.js` specifying the font to use

```js
...
theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['font', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
...
```

3. I have updated `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css`, importing the font

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "font";
    font-weight: bold;
    src: font-url("font.woff") format("woff");
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Inspecting the rendered code, my `tailwind-460c48e21c34697f1c9465bed5b183862eaf86c6.css` looks like

```css
@font-face{font-family:font;font-weight:400;src:font-url("/assets/font-bd33e45d79892555cff5f0452e65999105a249c9.woff") 

/*! tailwindcss v3.3.3 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com*/*,... html{...font-family:font,ui-sans-serif,system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji; ...
```

But, when pages are rendered, `system-ui` is used.

I'm running the app through the following `Procfile.dev`

```
web: bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 --early-hints
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch
```

After booting it, the log looks like

```
css | Running...
web | Running...
web | => Booting Puma
web | => Rails 7.0.7.2 application starting in development
web | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
web | Puma starting in single mode...
web | * Puma version: 6.3.1 (ruby 3.2.2-p53) ("Mugi No Toki Itaru")
web | *  Min threads: 5
web | *  Max threads: 5
web | *  Environment: development
web | *          PID: 18675
web | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
web | Use Ctrl-C to stop
css |
css | Rebuilding...
css |
css | Done in 498ms.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried to rebuild the assets? cause it looks like it is using the ones pre-compiled, not the ones you are changing dynamically

Comment: I have updated the questions with details regarding how I am running the app. From my understanding, the assets are automatically rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the **load order**:

In `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css` change it to this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
    font-family: "font";
    font-weight: bold;
    src: font-url("font.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Hope it helps :)